# Replace character in Excel file using psexcel in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

aI have xls files that I convert to csv files using powerhslle and the psexcel module. See code below.

```
import-module psexcel

$path_to_files = "C:\temp\MetaData_ORG"
$delimiter= "|"
$replacement=""

Get-ChildItem -Path $path_to_files –Recurse -Filter *.XLSX |

Foreach-Object {
$DestinationFile = $_.FullName.replace("xlsx","csv").replace("-",$replacement)
import-xlsx $_.FullName | Export-Csv  $DestinationFile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter $delimiter
}
```

However, those xlsx files often contain pipes `|` combined with quotes `"` in the textfields. That messes up the expoprt.

The thing is that there is no character that that can be used as a delimiter that is not present in the excel. The pipe is of those  the character the least prevalent character.  That is why the choice for the pipe.  Additionally to  that, once in a while there are double quotes in the Excel. The combination of a delimiter + double quotes in an Excel wreacs havovc when exporting to CSV. **EXCEPT** when I manually replace the pipe in the Excel with a space, underscore, empty string  or something like that **BEFORE** exporting to  csv using pipe.

The solution is simple: prior to converting the xlsx files using the code above, I open each xlsx file and replace all pipes `|` with a different character or an empty string. However, I feel the script could do that for me. Preferably using psexcel so I can do the whole proces on a machine that has no excel installed.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, I have no idea what your Excel files look like, but I suppose you could use `ConvertTo-Csv` using the default comma as delimiter, capture that as string, replace the pipes and then `ConvertFrom-Csv` again so you can export with that same pipe character as delimiter:

```
Import-Module psexcel

$path_to_files = "C:\temp\MetaData_ORG"
$delimiter     = "|"
$replacement   = ""

Get-ChildItem -Path $path_to_files –Recurse -Filter '*.xlsx' -File |
Foreach-Object {
    $DestinationFile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.FullName, 'csv').Replace("-", $replacement)
    (Import-Xlsx -Path $_.FullName | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-String).Replace($delimiter, $replacement) | 
     ConvertFrom-Csv | Export-Csv -Path $DestinationFile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter $delimiter
}
```

Comment: The thing is that there is no character that that can be used as a delimiter that is not present in the excel. The pipe is of those  the character the least prevalent character.  That is why the choice for the pipe.  Additionally to  that, once in a while there are double quotes in the Excel. The combination of a delimiter + double quotes in an Excel wreacs havovc when exporting to CSV. . EXCEPT when I manually replace the pipe in the Excel with a space, underscore, empty string  or something like that BEFORE exporting to  csv using pipe.

Comment: @Henrov without seeing an example... it shouldn't be a problem, because `ConvertTo-Csv` and `Export-Csv` both know what to do with let's say doiuble quotes as part of the field content. These will be doubled-up, which is the default way of dealing with characters like that in a csv file. Any software needing to import tha data should handle that correctly.